# Error while running "docker-compose up

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, docker-compose

I am getting error as "ERROR: client and server don't have same version (client : 1.21, server: 1.18)"

So I ran a command "export COMPOSE_API_VERSION=1.18" and now i am getting different error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
File "compose/cli/main.py", line 61, in main
File "compose/cli/main.py", line 113, in perform_command
File "compose/cli/main.py", line 835, in up
File "compose/project.py", line 374, in up
File "compose/project.py", line 415, in initialize
File "compose/network.py", line 162, in initialize
File "compose/network.py", line 47, in ensure
File "compose/network.py", line 82, in inspect
File "site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 32, in wrapper
docker.errors.InvalidVersion: inspect_network is not available for version < 1.21
docker-compose returned -1
```

my docker-compose file can be found at 
[gist](https://gist.github.com/pradeepb6/fb36e7344784b71a73074184eaabe0fc)

Docker Version : Docker version 1.12.0, build 8eab29e

Docker-compose : docker-compose version 1.8.0, build f3628c7

Ubuntu 14.04 64bit.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are running the latest version of docker (1.12) and docker-compose (1.8.0), locally. The error message implies that perhaps you're launching containers on a remote server? (started with [docker-machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/)?)

I suggest upgrading the version of docker running on the target server.

The documentation on the [COMPOSE_API_VERSION variable](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/docs/reference/envvars.md#compose_api_version) states that's only supposed to be used as a work-around.

> Setting this variable is intended as a workaround for situations where
>   you need to run temporarily with a mismatch between the client and
>   server version. For example, if you can upgrade the client but need to
>   wait to upgrade the server.
>
> Running with this variable set and a known mismatch does prevent some
>   Docker features from working properly. The exact features that fail
>   would depend on the Docker client and server versions. For this
>   reason, running with this variable set is only intended as a
>   workaround and it is not officially supported.
>
> If you run into problems running with this set, resolve the mismatch
>   through upgrade and remove this setting to see if your problems
>   resolve before notifying support.